# d3js - image not showing in arc

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a group with arc, and appending a `image` tag in it. in the `image` tag i am attaching a image using `xlink:href` but in the out put i am able to see anything.

any one help me to find the issue with my code:

here is my full code:

```
var dashBoardViewer =  function (params) {
    var container = params.container,
        width = params.width,
        height = params.height,
        groups = params.requiredGroup,
        inRadius = params.inRadius,
        outRadius = params.outRadius;

    return {
        init : function () {
            this.createSvg();
            this.createGroup();
        },
        createSvg : function () {
            this.svg = d3.select(container).append('svg').attr({
                width:width,
                height:height
            });
        },
        createGroup : function () {
            for(var i = 1; i <= groups; ++i) {
                var group = this.svg.append('svg:g')
                    .attr({
                        id : 'group'+i,
                        class:'group'
                    });
                this.arcCreator(group, i);
            }
        },

        arcCreator : function (group, index) {
            //move group
            switch (index) {
                case 1 : 
                    group.attr('transform', "translate("+outRadius+','+outRadius+")");
                    break;
                case 2 : 
                    group.attr('transform', "translate("+(width/2)+','+(outRadius*2)+")");
                    break;
                case 3 : 
                    group.attr('transform', "translate("+(width-outRadius)+','+outRadius+")");
                    break;
                case 4 : 
                    group.attr('transform', "translate("+outRadius*1.5+','+(height-outRadius)+")");
                    break;
                case 5 : 
                    group.attr('transform', "translate("+(width-(outRadius*1.5))+','+(height-outRadius)+")");
                    break;
            }

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                      .innerRadius(inRadius)
                      .outerRadius(outRadius-10) //deducting the stroke width
                      .startAngle(0)
                      .endAngle(360)

            return group.append("path")
                    .attr({"fill":"none",'stroke-width':5,'stroke':'#fff'})
                    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "s"+i;})
                    .attr("d",arc)
                    .append('image')
                    .attr({
                        "xlink:href":"images/circleImg.png", //nothing visible
                        width:257,
                        height:258
                    });
        }
    }
}

dashBoardViewer({
        container:'.container',
        width:1100,
        height:630,
        requiredGroup : 5,
        inRadius : 0,
        outRadius : 129
    }).init();
```

my html output : one of the group

```
<g id="group1" class="group" transform="translate(129,129)"><path fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="#fff" id="s0" d="M0,119A119,119 0 1,1 0,-119A119,119 0 1,1 0,119Z"><image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/circleImg.png" width="257" height="258"></image></path></g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing the `xlink:href` isn't correct. Try this:

```
.attr('xlink:href', 'path/to/image.png')
.attr('height', '258')
.attr('width', '257')
```

It's easier for d3 to understand those different attributes when they are split up. Also, if the `xlink:href` doesn't work, try just using `href`

**EDIT**

If you wanted to add a click handler, d3 has the ability to do that as well, but order is what matters. So let's take your example from earlier

```
return group.append("path")
    .attr({"fill":"none",'stroke-width':5,'stroke':'#fff'})
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "s"+i;})
    .attr("d",arc)
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'path/to/image.png')
    .attr('height', '258')
    .attr('width', '257')
```

If you wanted a click handler onto the path, you would put it right before you append the image, like so:

```
return group.append("path")
    .attr({"fill":"none",'stroke-width':5,'stroke':'#fff'})
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "s"+i;})
    .attr("d",arc)
    .on('click', /*insert function name or anonymous function*/)
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'path/to/image.png')
    .attr('height', '258')
    .attr('width', '257')
```

If you want it to be appended to the image, you would do that same little line of code, just further down so it is attached to the image

```
return group.append("path")
    .attr({"fill":"none",'stroke-width':5,'stroke':'#fff'})
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "s"+i;})
    .attr("d",arc)
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'path/to/image.png')
    .attr('height', '258')
    .attr('width', '257')
    .on('click', /*insert function name or anonymous function*/)
```

d3 also has the ability to do transitions which follow the format of `d3.transition()`. I haven't really gone too far into the transitions with d3, but Visual.ly did a [great blog post](http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/) explaining the basics of them. [d3's API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) is also very thorough in explaining how they work

Comment: yes, works. is it possible to select the childrens of a group on click and add some transitions?

Comment: Sure. I'll update my answer to elaborate on how you would do that.

Comment: As like  your suggestion the image is appends. but I am not able to see the image in the output. how to fix this?

Comment: Can you look here...http://jsfiddle.net/vft4f6v0/2/ - i am not able to see the image at all.. can you help me?

Comment: What is the end goal? To have the image inside the SVG circle?

Comment: As the way, as a expert, how can i adjust the letter space between my word. assume that, word length will be differed and dynamically supplied. if possible please help in this.